# Checking that CSS has been updated using capybara

Tags: css, ruby, selenium, capybara

I'm currently writing a web app that updates it's pages CSS based on user input.  I've got it all working fine, but I'm having trouble getting my automated tests to confirm that the CSS has actually been updated.

Basically, I just want to verify that the contents of a `<style>` tag in the document `<head>` have been updated to a certain value.  I'm using capybara (with the selenium driver) for my tests, with this code:

```
styles = page.all('style')
styles.length.should == 1
styles[0].text.should == style
```

It all works as expected, until the final line, which fails as it seems that `styles[0].text` is always "".  I've also tried `.value` but it is always `nil`.  I'm pretty sure the CSS is actually being updated, as I can see the changes in the firefox window that the tests are running in.

So, is there a way to get at the contents of the `<style>` tag using capybara?

Comment: Do I understand that you're trying to get at the contents of the `<style>` section in the documents HEAD?

Comment: @JonM Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Capybara (with Selenium at least, I didn't try any other drivers) won't show you this, I presume because the style content is wrapped in an HTML comment so it gets ignored e.g.:

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
    <!--
    .newfont { color:red; font-style:italic }
    -->
</STYLE>
```

You do, however, have access to the page's source with `page.source`, so you can use that to get at the style content.  The source is just a big string, so one way to dig into it is to parse it with Nokogiri (which is required by Capybara so you'll have it already):

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(page.source)
page.css('style').first.text

# => "\n&lt;!--\n.newfont { color:red; font-style:italic }\n--&gt;\n"
```

If you're asserting against customisable styles, and you're using Selenium anyway, an alternative solution could involve using Javascript to determine the calculated style of an element, there seems to be [no shortage](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+calculated+style) of information on doing this.  You could use Capybara's `page.evaluate_script` method to invoke a piece of Javascript that would tell you what a particular element actually looks like, and that may well be more robust than comparing the CSS text (e.g. if it gets minified by the app).

Comment: Getting the information from `page.source` works perfectly, thanks!  Might consider using javascript to verify calculated styles in the future, but at the moment I know exactly what to expect in the `<style>` so this way seems easiest.

Answer (score 1):

```
page.should have_css ".selector", :text => "Some Text"
page.should have_css ".selector", :value => "Some Value"
page.should have_css ".selector", :count => 1
```

Or

```
find('.selector').value
find('.selector:nth-child(1)').value
```

There are a couple ways to about what you are trying. I'd take a closer look at the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/#Finding).

Also, one thing to note, if you are trying to access these changes after a `javascript` event, you'll need to run this in Selenium (or equivalent). Or you could try to use Jasmine.js for this as well.

Comment: Though it's is slightly more concise, this solution seems to suffer from the same problem.  And I am running inside Selenium.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't realize you were going after the `<style>` tag. I think Jon M's solution is probably the way to go. Or you could try to get the `<style>` using normal methods then do a `should =~` against the content. I don't think you can get each style back as nodes/objects.